# part of UIButton is not responsive to touch events

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, touch

I have created a UIView with a subview of type UIButton. The button's size is bigger than the view's. Whenever I touch the button only the part that is the same size as superview is responsive to touch events. I created a drawing of view hierarchy to show you what I mean:

[image]

Only the red part of a button is responsive to touch events. Wht is this happening and how can I fix this?

This is the code in viewDidLoad, where I create the button programatically

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(-8, -8, 52, 52))
        moveView.addSubview(button)
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "trIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: "gogo", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        moveView.clipsToBounds = false
```

The UIView is created in storyboard.

Comment: umm isn't that how it works?? as your button is placed in the UIView only the area that is in the UIView will accept touches.

Comment: Does your superview really has to be smaller then button? Why? I don't know how it should works but this behaviour doesn't surprise me.

Comment: what is the frame of "moveView" if not solved yet

Comment: moveView is lower green view. It's size is smaller than the button's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the instruction as I tried your coding

```
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, giveValueLessthanMoveViewWidthSize, giveValueLessthanMoveViewHeightSize)) //Whatever give value less than your view size(x,y,width,height)

    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "trIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    button.addTarget(self, action: "gogo:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    moveView.clipsToBounds = false

    moveView.addSubview(button)
```

Then button action method

```
   func gogo(sender:UIButton!)
   {
     println("Button Clicked")
   }
```

Comment: thanks for stopping by. i actually wanted to create button bigger than view.

Comment: But if you create like that,the button touch response is depending on your view size only.Because you add the button to the view.moveView is SUPERCLASS and button is SUBCLASS.Subclass must under Superclass.

Comment: If you want to create button very large,first you need to create bigger or larger view first.

Comment: Please tick my answer.